# Latinoamérica, Hispanoamérica, or Sudamérica?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones

Latinoamérica, Hispanoamérica, Sudamérica or other?

For someone living in Venezuela or Chile, for example, what term would I be most likely to hear to describe countries south of the US?

The terms have different meanings, but I often use them synonymously. Is there a term that people in the Spanish-speaking world tend to use more, or are they just more precise with the terms than I am?

Comment: See this question: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1324/45

Comment: Dude this question is so broad you are likely to get a different a answer for every country south of the US border. And yet another for every subculture whiting those countries.

Comment: South America has nothing to do with been "south" of US.

Comment: There is no geographical name for "anything south of US". Not in English, not in Spanish, nor in any other language.

Comment: The term "south of the border" is American slang for a region that could stretch from Tijuana to Tierra del Fuego.  But most people use if to refer to Mexico, particularly the territory close to the border with the US.

Answer (score 18):

There are not synonymous, actually the diference is quite simple:

**Sudamérica:** Geographically, a subcontinent of "América", limited to the north by the Caribean sea. It does not include the Caribean, Central America ("Centroamérica") or North America ("Norteamérica"). Argentina, Brazil and Suriname are in "Sudamérica", but not Costa Rica, México or Cuba.

**Latinoamérica:** All american countries where a romance language (Spanish, Portuguese, French) is spoken as main language. Includes countries of South, North, Central America and the Caribean. Argentina, Brazil, Costa Rica, México and Cuba are in "Latinoamérica", but not Suriname. Particularly, Canada as country is not included despite French is spoken in some provinces.

**Hispanoamérica:** All american countries where Spanish is spoken as main language. Includes countries of South, North, Central America and the Caribean. Argentina, Costa Rica, México and Cuba are in "Hispanoamérica" but not Brazil or Suriname.

It's important to remark that there is no term to refer "all countries to the south of US", and the terms described before can't be used for that purpose.

"Latinoamérica", "Hispanoamérica" and "Iberoamérica" have cultural and linguistical implications, so are more complex to use. I would suggest to use "South America", "Central America" and "México" (only latin american country in North America) acording to the case, but I guess other people could think different.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add some examples. Sudamérica includes Argentina, Brazil and Suriname, but not Mexico. Latinoamérica includes Mexico, Argentina and Brazil, but not Suriname. Hispanoamérica includes Mexico and Argentina but not Brazil or Suriname.

Comment: I'd point out that Canada is not included in "Latinoamérica" even if there are French speaking areas in it because English is also spoken in that American country.

Comment: Nice answer! I suggest putting the very pertinent example of CesarGon. :) Keep up the good work!

Comment: This answer is good, but I think it's a bit incomplete. The terms are not synonymous, but in many circumstances more than one will technically be correct -- for example, if someone has moved to Peru, then one might say, "Fue vivir en _____". The question is, which would be preferred? (For example, in English, "he moved to South America" is more common than "he moved to Latin America", though both are correct.)

Comment: South America is more precise, since is a geographical term. But you have to be sure what you mean with "South America". For myself, I said "I'm from South America" cause I't clear an correct, but a mexican or costarican can't said the same. When I meet people from United States and they said "I'm american" I respond "Me too". "Latinamérica", "Hispanoamérica" and "Iberoamérica" have cultural and linguistical implications, so are more complex to use. I would suggest to use "South America", "Central America" and "México" (only latin american country in North America), it's neutral.

Comment: @Ricardo: in Spanish geography all of America is just one continent, but in English (and many others) it's two continents: North America and South America. Thus it's not correct to say that Mexico is only Latin country in North America - Central America is region within North American continent. Geographically Caribbean also belongs to North America.

Comment: @vartec: that's interesting, because that means "north america" and "Norteamérica" are not the same. I you look at the spanish wikipedia, you have articles for "Norte, Centro y Sur" América. Norte América only includes three countries according to Spanish wikipedia. That's what I learned in geography (América is one continent with three subcontinents). Maybe someone from other latinoamerican country could give more information. If you look at the english wikipedia, it's like you say. It looks like "continent" is neither a well-defined scientific concept. It's always good to learn something new

Comment: @Ricardo: That's because Norteamérica is not North America, but more like Northern America (although later doesn't include MX). As for continents, indeed there is no clear cut definition, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent

Comment: @vartec: ¿Tienes alguna referencia para "Northern america"?. Creo que alguna wikipedia tiene que corregirse, porque en la inglesa dice que "North America" es "América del norte" y las definiciones entre wikipedias no coinciden. De acuerdo con la definición de la RAE, norteamérica es Canadá, México y Estados Unidos solamente. Más tarde voy a investigar un poco más y poner referencias.

Comment: @Ricardo: pues me parece correcto - North America = America del norte; Northern America = Norteamerica; El problema con terminos geograficos es que no corresponden a 100%, asi que son tema dificil para traducir. En las definiciones de regiones de la ONU tambien tienes America del norte sin Mexico: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoesquema_de_las_Naciones_Unidas

Comment: ¡Gracias, @vartec! Pero creo que sigue el problema, para la RAE "Norteamérica" y "América del Norte" son sinónimos exactos. Entonces la traducción de estos términos no puede ser literal.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cuban writer Guillermo CAbrera Infante, the way to call the countries in America that share the Spanish language should be Hispanoamerica or Iberoamerica if we want to include Brazil as culutrally is closed to Hispanoamerica. GCI always was pointing out that Latinamerica was a ridiculos name, promoted by France to justify the French intervention in Mexico, whith Maximilan.

Answer (score 1):

Sudamérica: Los países del sur de Panamá, no incluyendo México o los países de América Central.

Latinoamérica: Los países en los que se habla español o portugués.

Hispanoamérica: Los países de Latinoamérica menos Brasil.

Comment: Del artículo [Latinoamérica en la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am%C3%A9rica_Latina): _Se debate la inclusión de Belice, la región francófona de Canadá, los estados y posesiones hispanohablantes de Estados Unidos en especial Puerto Rico e Islas Vírgenes de los Estados Unidos, y las posesiones francesas en América (Guadalupe, Guayana Francesa, Martinica, San Bartolomé y San Martín)._

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for Venezuela or Chile, but in Mexico the term most often used is

**Latinoamérica**