# ¿Hay alguna palabra para definir los países de América del Sur donde el español es la lengua oficial?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, hispanoamérica, nombres-propios, geografía

Sabemos que [Hispanoamérica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanoam%C3%A9rica) define aquellos países de América donde se habla español:

> [**hispanoamericano, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KW5espe)
>
> 1. adj. Natural de Hispanoamérica, conjunto de los países americanos donde el español es la lengua oficial. U. t. c. s.

Esto incluye buena parte de los países de América del Sur, casi todos los de América Central (menos Belize) y algunos del Caribe. <sup>Lista abajo</sup>

Después tenemos [Latinoamérica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am%C3%A9rica_Latina), que designa los países de América donde se habla (nótese que no se menciona la oficialidad) alguna lengua derivada del latín. A saber, español, portugués y francés.

Pero el otro día [tuvimos un pequeño debate con DGaleano y aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20571/1674) sobre cuál podría ser la palabra para designar otro concepto similar. Mirando en [Latinoamérica, Hispanoamérica, or Sudamérica?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1386/1674) veo definiciones interesantes, pero ninguna encaja con lo solicitado. Dado que no llegamos a ninguna conclusión convincente, os pregunto: ¿existe algún sustantivo que designe los países de América del Sur donde se habla español?

---

<sup>Los [Países americanos de habla hispana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanoam%C3%A9rica#Pa.C3.ADses_americanos_de_habla_hispana) son: Argentina, Bolivia, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, Cuba, República Dominicana, Ecuador, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, México, Nicaragua, Panama, Paraguay, Perú, Puerto Rico, Uruguay y Venezuela.</sup>

Visualmente, esta es la distinción entre Hispanoamérica, Latinoamérica, Sudamérica e Iberoamérica.

> [image]
> <sub>([sacado de Twitter](https://twitter.com/elOrdenMundial/status/964141037542428672))</sub>

Comment: Creo que el "pequeño debate" lo inicié yo :-) pero respecto a la pregunta, no conozco que exista tal denominación aunque nosotros tendemos a hablar de Suramérica haciendo caso omiso de Brasil. Nótese también que usamos más SuRamérica que SuDamérica contrario a lo que dice fundeu  http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/suramerica-o-sudamerica-147/

Comment: @DGaleano ¡perdona! Corregido, no tomé [tinto](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=GWGrtoHMix0AZs70aAK) hoy :D

Comment: @DGaleano interesante también lo de Su{D,R}américa, lo apunto para plantearlo en otra pregunta. A mí siempre me ha gustao decir América del Sur, de hecho.

Comment: Toda omisión se pude disculpar pero lo de no tomarse un tito de café **Colombiano** al empezar el día si es imperdonable!! jajajaja.

Comment: Interesante pregunta pero si encontráis la respuesta modificad la wikipedia ;) [Iberoamerica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberoam%C3%A9rica). Según el DPD *Nombre que recibe el conjunto de países americanos que formaron parte de los reinos de España y Portugal [..] iberoamericano, se refiere normalmente solo a lo perteneciente o relativo a Iberoamérica, esto es, a los países americanos de lengua española y portuguesa*. Pero no excluye a los países de lengua portuguesa. En que parte de la historia se tiene el orgullo de crear una palabra que los excluya?

Comment: En mi primer comentario dije que omitimos a Brasil y obviamente omití a las 3 Guyanas... y ya había tomado tinto :-)

Comment: Propongo (como punto de partida): *Hispanoamérica del Sur.*

Comment: Qué difícil. _¿América andino-platense..?_

Comment: ¿Qué tal _Hispanosudamérica_ o _Sudhispanoamérica_? O _Hispanosuramérica_ o _Surhispanoamérica_, como mejor suene.

Comment: Se puede llamar hispanoamérica, O latinoamérica y también incluye a brasil ya que el portugués se le considera hispanidad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La respuesta parece ser: no existe una palabra para denominar a los países de Suramérica donde se habla español.

Con "más de una" palabra sería posible:

> Países suramericanos de habla hispana/española.

o

> Suramérica menos las Guyanas y Brasil.

siendo obviamente la primera opción la mejor

<sub>O podríamos popularizar este "invento": surhispanoamérica</sub>

Comment: ¡Me gusta el invento! Diría _surhisp_ para darle mejor SEO :)

Comment: Para complementar la respuesta dejo este video muy ilustrativo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBt5rMD2aDc